# Angular: Reference current component in event listener on window

Tags: angular, constructor

I have a component in my Angular app that has a property `this.prop1`, and in the constructor I add an event listener on the `window` object. In it I try to reference `this.prop1` from the current component. So my constructor looks like this:

```
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      console.log(this.prop1);
    });
  }
```

This throws a warning that the window object does not have a property called `this.prop1`, so I guess the context (the value of `this`) in the callback in `window`.

**What I Want To Know:**

How do I reference `this.prop1` from the current component in this callback, given that the context is `window`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use fat [arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function like below:

You can check out this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ovzbez), maybe it'll help you!

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
   window.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=> {    
      console.log(this.prop1);
   });
}
```

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not
>   present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this
>   from its enclosing scope.